# Best way to index table for speeding up order by

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have following table structure.

```
town:

id (MEDINT,PRIMARY KEY,autoincrement), 
town(VARCHAR(150),not null),
lat(FLOAT(10,6),notnull)
lng(FLOAT(10,6),notnull)
```

i frequently use "SELECT * FROM town ORDER BY town" query. I tried indexing town but it is not being used. So what is the best way to index so that i can speed up my queries.

USING EXPLAIN(UNIQUE INDEX Is PRESENT ON town):

```
 mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM studpoint_town order by town \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: studpoint_town
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
    Extra: Using filesort
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ragards ,
ravi.

Comment: How do you know that the index on `town` is not being used?  Could you post the output of `EXPLAIN` for your query?  Have you tried to give an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html) e.g. `SELECT * FROM town FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (index_name) ORDER BY town`?

Comment: @eggyal i updated explain result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EXPLAIN` output indicates that currently the `studpoint_town` table has only 3 rows.  As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html):

> The output from [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html) shows `ALL` in the `type` column when MySQL uses a table scan to resolve a query. This usually happens under the following conditions:
>
> [...]
>
> - The table is so small that it is faster to perform a table scan than to bother with a key lookup. This is common for tables with fewer than 10 rows and a short row length. Don't worry in this case.